# How can i store coordinates in c# for use in a graphics engine

Tags: c#, 3d, projection

I am trying to understand how 3d graphics works in its entirety and I have came across an issue with how to store my coordinates. My challenge is to program the whole code with minimal dependencies because I plan to be able to port this to several languages. I am pretty new to c# and I want to be able to call these variables which will be preset with Vert.x or something similar. My projection math is

> r = w/h, a = 1/tan(θ/2), projected x = arx/z, projected y = ay/z the z
> coordinate isn't needed atm but it would be q = (zfar/(zfar-znear)
> projected z = zq - znear*q

I don't want to use matrices either. For the coordinates I need to be able to input them per vertex. I want to also be able to store a lot of vertices in one large list somehow. Any help would be really appreciated.
I will answer any questions. The code can't really be created until I at least have this problem sorted cause everything is built off this
I also need to store 3 sets of coordinates per triangle

In c++ the code would be something similar to this

```
struct vec3d
{
    float x, y, z;
};

struct triangle
{
    vec3d p[3];
};

struct mesh
{
    vector<triangle> tris;
};

mesh meshCube;
```

```
meshCube.tris = {

        // SOUTH
        { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
        { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },

        // EAST                                                      
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },

        // NORTH                                                     
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },

        // WEST                                                      
        { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
        { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },

        // TOP                                                       
        { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },

        // BOTTOM                                                    
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },

        };
```

Comment: Create a triangle object with the required List of coordinate objects which have their x, y, and z values.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

your vec3d struct is fine (you'll need to add some stuff like addition/etc...)
I've made my own engine and here is how i've done.

- I have a mesh class (with interfaces and stuff) that contains :

  - List(vec3d)
  - List(Triangle)
  - other stuff of course (texture/normals/colors etc...)
- Triangle class:

  - List(uint) for triangle indices.

each triangle indices points to the mesh List index.

When mapping it on to the graphics card :

```
foreach (var face in Mesh.Faces)
                if (!face.IsDeleted)
                {
                    var indices = face.GetVertexIndexes();
                    foreach (var vertexIndex in indices)
                        array[index++] = vertexIndex;
                }
```

where "array" is the pointer to the indices array that will be mapped on GPU

and for mapping the vertices (PositionBuffer being the vec3d array that will be mapped on the GPU):

```
PositionBuffer = Mesh.Vertices.Select((x) => x.Position).ToArray().GenVertexBuffer(VBOConfig.Vec3, BufferUsage.DynamicDraw);
```